# Input multiple strings in command line argument and call it into another class in Java

Tags: java, string, command

I'm still new to Java and I was assigned a program to change the entire string into lower case or upper case depending on the first character of the string. I've done the program to read one string from the command line and for the next assignment, instead of only one string, I need to read multiple strings from command line argument and input it into another class from main class. The problem is I don't know how to do it because it changes my variable from str to str[]. Is there anyone can help me.

Here's my program

```
class Strcov{
    
    static String toULCase(String str) {
        
        //Converting string into ASCII value
        char word = str.charAt(0);
        int ascii = word;
        
        //If string start with uppercase, then the whole string turn to uppercase
        //[65,90] is the range for uppercase letter in ASCII
        if(ascii<=90 && ascii >= 65) {
            str = str.toUpperCase();
        }
        
        //If string start with lowercase, then the whole string turn to lowercase
        //[97,122]is the range for lowercase letter in ASCII
        else if(ascii<=122&& ascii>=97) {
            str=str.toLowerCase();
        }
        
        //If does not match, return string value as it is
        return str;
        
    }
    
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Strcov obj= new Strcov();
        String str= args[0];
            
        System.out.print(obj.toULCase(str));
    }

}
```

and here what I do to make it able to read multiple strings from command line argument,

```
class Strcov{
    
    static String toULCase(String str[]) {
        
        //Converting string into ASCII value
        char word = str.charAt(0);
        int ascii = word;
        
        //If string start with uppercase, then the whole string turn to uppercase
        //[65,90] is the range for uppercase letter in ASCII
        if(ascii<=90 && ascii >= 65) {
            str = str.toUpperCase();
        }
        
        //If string start with lowercase, then the whole string turn to lowercase
        //[97,122]is the range for lowercase letter in ASCII
        else if(ascii<=122&& ascii>=97) {
            str=str.toLowerCase();
        }
        
        //If does not match, return string value as it is
        return str;
        
    }
    
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Strcov obj= new Strcov();
        String str[];
        
        for(int i =0; i<args.length; i++) {
            str[i]=args[i];
            System.out.print(obj.toULCase(str[i]));
        }
    }

}
```

This require some changes in the Strcov class and I dont know how to.

Comment: What's your error?

Comment: Just remove the proxy array str and pass the Strings from args dircetly, the rest seems correct

Comment: Wow it works, i didnt even know it was that simple I thought that I need to change the whole program. Thanks a lot.